# What does mode 'x' mean in NeoVim?

Tags: neovim

As title. What does the abbreviation `'x'` mean in NeoVim? I just saw people setting up `keymap.set` with this abbreviation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are two modes often confused as one:

- `:h Visual-mode`
- `:h Select-mode`

The indicator or prefix used in keymaps for these modes are:

- `:h mapmode-x`: activated only in visual mode
- `:h mapmode-s`: activated only in select mode
- `:h mapmode-v`: activated in both visual and select mode

The difference between select-mode and visual-mode can be found in `:h Select-mode`. As for the keymap distinction, vim suggests the following in `:h mapmode-x`:

> NOTE: Mapping a printable character in Select mode [`mapmode-v`] may confuse the user.  It's better to explicitly use :xmap and :smap for printable characters.

---

**TL;DR**: When in doubt, use strictly `visual-mode` and `mapmode-x`.

Comment: I just changed every occurrence of 'v's in my neovim's config. Thanks for the careful-minded answer!